# Abrir ventana de explorador de ´windows´ con un boton usando ´jquery´ no me funciona en ´safari´?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Tengo el siguiente código para abrir el explorador de windows para seleccionar un archivo:

```
$('#btnCargarArchivo').click(function () {
    $('#form-filtro').prop('submit', null);
    $('#form-filtro').unbind();
    $("#file-fichero").trigger('click');
 });
```

me funciona en firefox, chrome pero en safari no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunas veces no es necesario utilizar `JS`.

La etiqueta [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/label) provee el funcionamiento que buscar imitar:

> El Elemento **HTML < label>** representa una etiqueta para un elemento en una interfaz de usuario. Este puede estar asociado con un control ya sea mediante la utilizacion del atributo **for**, o ubicando el control dentro del elemento label. Tal control es llamado *"el control etiquetado"* del elemento label.

### Ejemplo:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<label for="file">
  Subir archivo
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

Comment: Disculpa edite la pregunta, el evento es usando un boton @Marcos

Comment: @AlcidesSalazar, por que tiene que ser un `button`? cual es el problema de hacerlo con un `label`?